# Codefirst foreign key name has repeated table name - how to set explicitly?

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 tables:
1) Parent
2) Child

In codefirst I have the following definition:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> child { get; set; }
}
```

However in the db, the child table has the following foreign key defined:

ParentParentId (FK, int, NULL)

How do I ensure it just specifies ParentId in the foreign key?  Do I need to explicitly set the parent key using the fluent configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must either include Foreign key property in the child entity:

```
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } // FK
    public virtual Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Or you must rename the column with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Parent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Childs)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

Comment: great that worked! I used the 1st solution. Whats the significance of the 'virtual' keyword?  I also noticed that with the 2nd solution doesn't work, the Map() method is not available using WithMany(). I only have HasForeignKey, IsIdependent and WillCascadeOnDelete methods, no Map()!

Comment: You are not using last version of EF code first. That is the reason why you don't see `Map` and instead you have `IsIndependent`. The reason for `virtual` is enabling lazy loading of `Parent`.